Assign a length 1 numpy array to a cell of pandas DataFrame
I am trying to assign a numpy array whose length is 1 to a cell of pandas DataFrame. When the array's length is greater than one, the cell is still a sized numpy.ndarray, and I can use the len command to retrieve the length. However, if I assign an array of length 1, I receive an error message saying len() of unsized object. I want to be able to assign an ndarray to a cell once at a time and when the length of the ndarray is 1, I can still access its length using len method.
When the array's length is greater than one, the cell is still a sized numpy.ndarray, and I can use the len command to retrieve the length, e.g.,
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
df.loc[2, 'A']=np.arange(2)
print(df)
print(len(df.loc[2, 'A']), type(df.loc[2, 'A']))

and the output is
        A    B    C
0     NaN  NaN  NaN
1     NaN  NaN  NaN
2  [0, 1]  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN
2 <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

However, if I assign an array of length 1, I can no longer use the len method
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
df.loc[2, 'A']=np.arange(1)
print(df)
print(type(df.loc[2, 'A']))
print(len(df.loc[2, 'A']))

the output looks like this
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    0  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

and receive an error message saying:
TypeError: len() of unsized object

Weirdly, if I assign multiple cells at the same time, the len method is still available
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
df.loc[[1,2], 'A']=np.arange(1), np.arange(1)
print(df)
print(type(df.loc[2, 'A']))
print(len(df.loc[2, 'A']))

and the output is
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  [0]  NaN  NaN
2  [0]  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
1

I want to be able to assign an ndarray to a cell once at a time and when the length of the ndarray is 1, I can still access its length using len method.
I appreciate your help.

From staging ground:  While this looks like an x/y problem (and I'm still not entirely convinced it isn't) it appears instead to be a hack/workaround to a required package.

Thank you very much for pointing that out. I didn't realise that my question could be an x/y problem. Instead of using len(df.loc[2, 'A']),  df.loc[2, 'A'].size fixes the problem of getting the size of an array. Instead of forcing the cell to be a 1d array, I convert the cell using np.atleast_1d() as suggested by @DanielF right before other array operations. Now the code could run with no problem.

One option, although a bit verbose, would be to pass a Series with the correct index on the right hand side:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=np.arange(5))
df = df.astype(object)

idx = [2]
df.loc[idx, 'A'] = pd.Series([np.arange(1)], index=idx)

Output:
     A    B    C
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  [0]  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN

Complete example:
idx = [2]
df.loc[idx, 'A'] = pd.Series([np.arange(1)], index=idx)
idx = [2]
df.loc[idx, 'B'] = pd.Series([np.arange(2)], index=idx)
idx = [1, 2]
df.loc[idx, 'C'] = pd.Series([np.arange(1), np.arange(1)], index=idx)

Output:
     A       B    C
0  NaN     NaN  NaN
1  NaN     NaN  [0]
2  [0]  [0, 1]  [0]
3  NaN     NaN  NaN
4  NaN     NaN  NaN


Is there a way to keep the type of the cell of df as np.ndarray?

This changes the data type to <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>.

I think you should be able to use np.atleast_1d for this:
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
df=df.astype(object)
df.loc[2, 'A'] = np.atleast_1d(0)
print(df)
print(type(df.loc[2, 'A']))
print(len(df.loc[2, 'A']))

It should always make 1d arrays, even out of constants.  It will even work on multiple inputs, similarly to your final example.

Somebody please test, my IT department broke my python environment >.<

Unfortunately this won't work, np.atleast_1d(0) is no different than np.arange(1).
